# when should I use a tuned amplifier circuit compared to a LCR bandpass circuit?

Tags: analog, filter, signal

I am reading Microelectronic Circuits by Sedra and Smith. When should I use a tuned amplifier circuit compared to a LCR bandpass circuit? The text does not explain it well.

Comment: Whenever you need the output signal of greater power than the input.

Comment: @DeskReference are you done with this Q and A now?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, I forgot to accept the answer. Did it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *When should I use a tuned amplifier circuit compared to a LCR bandpass
> circuit?*

In power applications, you have to use passive components for filtering because to try and use a transistor or amplifier is missing the point. So, if you have a QI type charger circuit and you are trying to pass energy from a transmit coil to receive coil, you would only use passive components for producing voltage amplification efficiently. There is no feasible option to use regular amplifiers tuned or otherwise.

However, if you are trying to amplify an RF signal prior to demodulation it makes sense to use a tuned amplifier because you are trying to increase the power of your signal.